# javax.jms.MessageListener: What additional threading concerns to take care of?

Tags: java, spring, jms

In [this](http://bsnyderblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/using-spring-to-receive-jms-messages.html) nice article on JMS, Bruce Snyder (Author of "ActiveMQ in Action") mentions:

> [one] of the options for implementing a message listener to be used with the Spring DMLC is using javax.jms.MessageListener - It is a standardized interface from the JMS spec **but handling threading is up to you**.

He doesnt talk about threading in the other two options: Spring SessionAwareMessageListener and MessageListenerAdapter.

My question is: What additional threading concerns are to be addressed with the use of the plain javax.jms.MessageListener, compared to the other two approaches ?

I am thinking that regardless of what option I choose from the above 3, if my listener will be receiving messages on multiple threads, my listener implementation has to be thread-safe.

I went through the examples Bruce had created in [github](https://github.com/bsnyder/spring-jms-examples/blob/master/async/message-listener) for all the three options.
I didnt see any specific handling for threads in any case.
The xmls of [simple](https://github.com/bsnyder/spring-jms-examples/blob/master/async/message-listener/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/consumer-jms-context.xml) and [session-aware](https://github.com/bsnyder/spring-jms-examples/blob/master/async/session-aware-message-listener/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/consumer-jms-context.xml)  consumers are almost the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your not keeping any state in your `MessageListener` implementations(through say an instance variable), you don't have to worry about thread-safety with any of the three approaches. If you are keeping state, then like in any multi-threading scenario, you will have to take care of how you synchronize access to the state.

Comment: I thought so too, as mentioned in my question. Just wanted to make sure am not overlooking anything, as I am new to this.